# Can I have several XML layout files and only one main class?

Tags: android-studio

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a few different XML layout files without a separate class file for each? If so, how would I go about changing the layout file that the class is using on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

You can have different `.xml` files. To get them you need to call in the specific `method` `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout1);` I recommend to take a look at the android developer [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout) to get a basic knowhow of what is a layout used for. `Themes` could be interesting for you also.